# how to add condition before scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have a problem with fullpage.js library
I need the screen to not scroll when my modal is open.

I tried onLeave , afterLoad and disable scrolling with jQuery like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).bind("wheel", function (e) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("modalIsOpen").length != 0) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
    } else {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
    }
  });
  $("#fullpage").fullpage({
    normalScrollElements: ".tableContainer",
  });
});
```

but the issue with this code is page scrolls once and after the first scroll, finally the page scroll stops working
It seems that fullpage.js scrolls first , after that jQuery deactivates scroll.
any Idea ?
thanks guys

Comment: its not actually clear which call back function you used it in.  update your full code so that the mistake could be seen

Comment: I would disable the fullscrolling when the modal is displayed, not checking it when user starts to scroll in the wheel or scroll event

Comment: @JavierFromMadrid hi , you are right but there are some problem with this approach . when I call  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false); in my ModalOpen() function it works great and fullpagejs stop scrolling page . but unfortunatly the modal scrollbar also stops working . so it seems  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false) is blocking all wheel and scrolls so that I have my scrollbar in modal but it isnt working with wheel up . 
so Do you have a solution that can disable the full page scrolling, but let the modal scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @JavierFromMadrid I found the solution
but it is not an exact answer to the topic question, but it is a different solution to solve the problem
One way to solve this problem is to disable fullpagejs scrolling when the modal is opened :

```
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
```

In order for the called function not to disable the modal scroll, it is necessary to define the name of the medal class in the fullpage **normalScrollElements** option.

```
 $("#fullpage").fullpage({
    normalScrollElements: ".modal",
  });
```

Comment: The other option would be to call `setAllowScrolling` when you open the modal. Not on scroll.